# Undefined reference issue when trying to display a DICOM file using Qt and VTK

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, vtk

I am trying to develop a simple DICOM viewer using VTK 7.1 and Qt 5.5.1 under Ubuntu, though when trying to compile the project on my terminal or using Creator several undefined reference errors come into play...

Result :

```
libDigitalImagingLib.so : undefined reference to 'vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL2_AutoInit_Construct()'
libDigitalImagingLib.so : undefined reference to 'vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL2_AutoInit_Construct()'
libDigitalImagingLib.so : undefined reference to 'vtkImageViewer2::New()'
```

The relevant code for my project for this case looks like this...

CMakeLists.txt

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT (DigitalImaging)

FIND_PACKAGE (VTK)
INCLUDE (${VTK_USE_FILE})

FIND_PACKAGE (Qt5Widgets)

SET (DigitalImagingLib_src ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/mainwindow.cpp)
SET (DigitalImagingLib_hdr ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/mainwindow.h)
SET (DigitalImagingLib_ui ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/mainwindow.ui)
SET (DigitalImagingBin_src ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cxx)

qt5_wrap_cpp(DigitalImagingLib_hdr_moc ${DigitalImagingLib_hdr})
qt5_wrap_ui(DigitalImagingLib_ui_moc ${DigitalImagingLib_ui})

include_directories (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories (${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})

add_library (DigitalImagingLib SHARED
    ${DigitalImagingLib_src}
    ${DigitalImagingLib_hdr_moc}
    ${DigitalImagingLib_ui_moc}
)

target_link_libraries (DigitalImagingLib Qt5::Widgets)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(DigitalImaging
    ${DigitalImagingBin_src}
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (DigitalImaging
    ${VTK_LIBRARIES}
    DigitalImagingLib
)
```

mainwindow.cpp :

```
# include "mainwindow.h"
# include "ui_mainwindow.h"

# include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
# include <vtkImageViewer2.h>
# include <vtkDICOMImageReader.h>
# include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
# include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
# include <vtkRenderer.h>
# include <QVTKWidget.h>

...

void MainWindow::displayDICOM(std::string file) {
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMImageReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMImageReader>::New();
    reader -> SetFileName(file.c_str());
    reader -> Update();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2> imageViewer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2>::New();
    imageViewer -> SetInputConnection(reader -> GetOutputPort());
    imageViewer -> SetRenderWindow(ui -> vtkRenderer -> GetRenderWindow());
    imageViewer -> Render();
}

...
```

As a beginner would really appreciate any kind of help and tips on best coding practices for CMake! Perhaps it is worth mentioning I tried to implement the following without any remarkable success (It seems to do the same)...

```
# include "vtkAutoInit.h"

VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL2)
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you missed adding VTK libraries in your DigitalImagingLib, since the error comes with libDigitalImagingLib.so

```
target_link_libraries (DigitalImagingLib Qt5::Widgets ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion, upon revisiting my CMakeLists.txt I found a couple of extras and missing features :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
        mainwindow.h
        #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
        #define MAINWINDOW_H
        
        #include <QMainWindow>
        #include <QWidget>
        
//---Headers for reading, rendering and interacting with the DICOM---//
        #include <vtkNew.h>
        #include <vtkRenderer.h>
        #include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
        #include <vtkImageViewer2.h>
        #include <vtkDICOMImageReader.h>
        #include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
        #include <vtkNamedColors.h>
        
        
        QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
        namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
        QT_END_NAMESPACE
        
        class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
        {
            Q_OBJECT
        
        public:
            MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
            ~MainWindow();
//---Declaring the DICOM reader and viewer---//
            vtkNew<vtkNamedColors> colors;
            vtkNew<vtkDICOMImageReader> dicomReader;
            vtkNew<vtkImageViewer2> imageviewer;
        
            void showDICOMImage();
        
        
        protected:
        
        
        private:
            Ui::MainWindow *ui;
        
        
        
        };
        #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
    
    ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    
        mainwindow.cpp
        #include "mainwindow.h"
        #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
//---Includes for integrating the VTK with the QT---//
        #include <vtkAutoInit.h>
        VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL2);
        VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkInteractionStyle);
        VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingFreeType);
        
        
        MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
            : QMainWindow(parent)
            , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
        {
           // ui->setupUi(this);
              showDICOMImage();
        }
        
        MainWindow::~MainWindow()
        {
            delete ui;
        }
        
//---Function to read and visualise the DICOM---//

        void MainWindow::showDICOMImage()
        {
        
            //---Reading the DICOM---// 
            
//1.---Giving the absolute path of the DICOM to be read---//
            QString path="D:/Series1/37245458.dcm";

//2.---Reading it with the DICOM reader defined earlier---//        
               dicomReader->SetFileName(path.toUtf8().constData());
               dicomReader->Update();
               dicomReader->UpdateInformation(); 
//3.---Viewing the DICOM by passing the reader into the viewer---//
               imageviewer->SetInputData(dicomReader->GetOutput());


               imageviewer->Render();
        
            //---Visualising the DICOM---//

//1.---Declaring the interactor---//
               vtkNew<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>renderWindowInteractor; 
//2.---Setting/Passing the interactor into the viewer---//
               imageviewer->SetupInteractor(renderWindowInteractor);
               renderWindowInteractor->Start();
        
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).